# Passport google-OAuth 2.0 strategy - TokenError: Bad Request

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth, passport.js

I am getting  the user details after successful authentication in passport's `passport-google-oauth2` strategy.

Here is the configuration of google strategy with passport:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { VerifyCallback, Strategy as googleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth2';

passport.use(
    new googleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: 'clientId',
            clientSecret: 'ClientSecret',
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:9000/v1/hello',
            passReqToCallback: true,
        },
        function (request: Request, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: {}, done: VerifyCallback) {
            console.log({ profile });
            return done('an error occured', profile);
        }
    )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('serialize', user);
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('deserialize', user);
    done(null, user);
});
```

Here is the router code where I am calling google auth in the routes file

```
import passport from 'passport';

import '@utils/passport.utils';

const router: Router = Router();
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());

router.route('/google').get(
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    })
);

export const userRoutes = { path: '/user', router };
```

I have initialised the express-session in the app.ts file.

I have enabled the google+ api in the google console. Am I missing something?

This is the hello request where I am getting the user data:

```
router.route('/hello').get(passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        return res.locals.success('Hello World');
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

In this hello endpoint I am getting authenticated users profile data but I am also getting this error as well: `TokenError: Bad Request`